# Exiting WebView which lies inside a JFrame outside JavaFX thread

Tags: java, oop, webview, jframe, javafx-2

I have some code which adds a `Java FX WebView` to a JFrame. This works great. Once the user has visited a specific website, I'm trying to programatically close this JFrame, first by calling `Platform.exit()` and then `frame.dispose()`. This works fine as long as I call this method from the same thread that the `WebView` was started from.

However, this is what I am trying to avoid. [**Consider the following code (http://pastebin.com/kAjweLi5)**](http://pastebin.com/kAjweLi5).
This code tries to shut down the program when the URL changes. However, this results in:

> IllegalStateException: Attempt to call defer when toolkit not running 
>   (**[stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/mJqvYAGn)**)

Update:
Using my (very limited) debuggning knowledge, I realized that the `exit()` method seems to successfully run. Image of the stack:

[image]

*(the error occures when the yellow line is executed)*

**How can I close the JFrame from another thread/class, without getting the above exception?**

Comment: @sbridges Stacktrace posted (http://pastebin.com/mJqvYAGn) along with new code example to better illustrate my problem. Your help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From previously (amended) post:

```
public void exit()
{
   Platform.runLater( new Runnable(){@Override public void run(){
      System.err.println( "exit/runLater/run" );
      webEngine.getLoadWorker().cancel();
      Platform.exit();
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){ @Override public void run() {
         System.err.println( "exit/invokeLater/run" );
         frame.dispose(); }});
      }});
}
```

It's necessary to shutdown background threads

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Replacing my exit method with yours still results in the same error.. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The work is done! I copy-paste your code in my bench and I finally find the right way: no exception for me...

Comment: I can't express how much I appreciate your help; this has been bugging me for days ;-). Thanks a million!!

Comment: It's a pleasure, I have a large smile on my face ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is late, but this might be helpful for someone.

```
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            engine.getLoadWorker().cancel();    
            Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        }
    });
```

I ran into several issues, but finally this worked for me without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about JavaFX, but I guess the listener will be executed on the JavaFX thread, which is good for `Platform.exit()`, but not so much for the Swing command `frame.dispose()`.  You could try sending that last command to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

If that does not work, can you try to get more information about the error from the debugger since the stack trace is not linked to any line in your code?

Comment: I tried to combine your answer with Marek's, which resulted in replacing my `exit()` method with this: http://pastebin.com/vvHikh5b . That didn't help though, it still gives the exact same error (and bad stacktrace).

Comment: I'm pretty new with Java, how does one get more information from the debugger? Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: It is tricky to debug since it is multi-threaded.  I would put a breakpoint at the start of your exit method and step from there.  You could also just add print statements in your code (the poor man's debugger) to figure out which line is never reached.

Comment: Using my very limited debugging skills, I've discovered that both the `Platform.runLater()` and the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` successfully executes. The problem seems to occur when `exit()` is called again(?)..? Updated OP with picture :-)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't have JavaFX installed, but as far as I remember you should use javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Runnable runable) to perform any operations on GUI. JavaFX and Swing aren't thread safe. So it should be:

```
...
public void exit() {
  final Test self = this;
  Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    self.frame.dispose();
  });
  Platform.exit();
}
...
```

You close platform before disposing frame. Dispose the frame first. After Platform.exit your application can be in strange state with some resources closed, some inaccessible, ...

Comment: Hmm, I tried to replace my `exit()` method with yours (http://pastebin.com/Wgz5mTTB), however, that resulted in the same exteption. (Stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/PTCiVGv4)..

Comment: Regarding your update: I now tried to dispose the frame first, which didn't change anything. Thanks a lot for your help so far!